Access VPN client
I’ve two houses one with the VPN server and another with VPN client.
At the house one:
VPN server: Asus 5202T l2tp IPsec.
Server IP: 192.168.1.10
VPN addresses: 10.0.3.1/24
At the house two:
Client VPN:
VPN IP: 10.0.3.4
IP: 192.168.8.1
From the house two I can access to 192.168.1.10 (server) or the router 192.168.1.1.
But on the contrary, from the house one I cannot access to the router: 10.0.3.4 or 192.168.8.1.
Do you know how can I access to the router of the house two from the house one?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
